# Move a range of elements within array without extra memory?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, swap

Essentially I have an array like this: `[1, 2, 3, 9, 9, 4, 5, 6, 7]`

I want to move the `[1, 2, 3]` part before `[4, 5, 6, 7]` like this: `[9, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]` while this preserving the order of the rest of the array.

An easy way is just allocate a temp array to fit `[1, 2, 3]` while I shift the rest of the array left, but I want to do this without consuming any extra memory. Is this possible? Perhaps some swap-technique?

EDIT: to clarify, it is a large STL array, and by extra memory I mean no extra large heap allocation, temporary variables are fine.

EDIT2: I am looking for a solution for any given array and any range inside it

Comment: Show your work first. Please give the prototype. When you say no extra memory, will you allow a for loop to have an index variable and a swap variable, or do you just mean "no arbitrarily large allocation of temp space"? Is this for a std container or a C array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [std::rotate](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/rotate/), like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main () {
    std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3, 9, 9, 4, 5, 6, 7};
    for (auto i : v) {
        std::cout << i << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::rotate(v.begin (), v.begin () + 3, v.begin () + 5);
    for (auto i : v) {
        std::cout << i << " ";  
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 9 9 4 5 6 7 
9 9 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to swap two numbers, without using a temp, which is possible, like this:

```
/**
* Swap the parameters without a temp variable.
* Warning! Susceptible to overflow/underflow.
* @param a The first parameter.
* @param a The second parameter.
*/
void swapNoTemp(int& a, int& b)
{
    a -= b;
    b += a;// b gets the original value of a
    a = (b - a);// a gets the original value of b
}
```

but as I discuss [here](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/swap-without-using-extra-variable-c/), it should be used with extreme caution (and my opinion is that the trade-off between caution and memory gain that you get is not fair).

---

Example of main function to use this:

```
int main()
{
    int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 9, 9, 4, 5, 6, 7};
    swapNoTemp(a[0], a[2]);
    swapNoTemp(a[0], a[4]);
    swapNoTemp(a[1], a[3]);
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
        std::cout << a[i] << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Georgioss-MacBook-Pro:~ gsamaras$ g++ -Wall main.cpp 
Georgioss-MacBook-Pro:~ gsamaras$ ./a.out 
9 9 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

For another approach, with XOR, check the comments in my link or this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43924781/2411320).

---

Another, general way, to do this is to use [std::rotate](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/rotate/), as shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43925210/2411320).

Comment: std::copy overwrittes the element in destination no? Also is there a generic swap-solution for any arbitrary array and range?

Comment: @KaiserJohaan ah good point, updated! There is the one with XOR, but still I wouldn't advice you to use it, the reasons remain the ones I stated in post. Answer updated!

Answer (score 1):

Or the more famous and faster XOR option:

```
void swap(int &a, int &b) {
    b ^= a;
    a ^= b;
    b ^= a;
}
```

Comment: Right, copy pasted from the [comments](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/swap-without-using-extra-variable-c/) from my link, doomista  said: "It’s overflow proof. But according to [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm), compiler optimization can result in even faster and memory equivalent solution when using extra variable, so I guess thats the best solution so far when you’re not working at assembly level.". +1

Comment: *faster XOR option* -- Saw a presentation the other day that shows that this is **not** faster than what a modern day C++ compiler can produce when swapping two integers.